# Creating a multidimensional array tree from MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to organize my mysql table into a multidimension php tree array.

For example, I'm trying to organize my products in a hierarchy for easy selection to narrow down the result the narrower they go in the result.

I am returned mysql rows like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 1
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HD
    [3] => WiFi
    [4] => 7"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 16GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 2
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HD
    [3] => WiFi
    [4] => 7"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 32GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 3
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HD
    [3] => WiFi
    [4] => 8.9"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 16GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 4
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HD
    [3] => WiFi
    [4] => 8.9"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 32GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 5
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HD
    [3] => 4G LTE
    [4] => 8.9"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 32GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 6
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HD
    [3] => 4G LTE
    [4] => 8.9"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 64GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 7
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HDX
    [3] => Wifi
    [4] => 7"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 16GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 8
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HDX
    [3] => Wifi
    [4] => 7"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 32GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 9
)
Array
(
    [1] => Amazon
    [2] => Kindle Fire HDX
    [3] => Wifi
    [4] => 7"
    [5] => 
    [6] => 64GB
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 10
)
```

...etc

Note the last array value is the Product ID.

And I'm looking for help writing a recursive function that will result in an array that looks like:

```
Array(
    'Amazon' => Array(
         'Kindle Fire' => 1,
         'Kindle Fire HD' => Array(
              'WiFi' => Array(
                  '7"' => Array(
                      '16GB' => 2,
                      '32GB' => 3
                  )
                  '8.9"' => Array(
                      '16GB' => 4,
                      '32GB' => 5
                  )
              )
         )

    )
)
```

I've tried something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
    $id = $row[0];
    unset($row[0]);
    unset($row[count($row)]);
        $row[] = $id; // Moves id to last array value

    for($i = 1; $i < count($row); $i++) {
        if($i == 1) {
            if(!array_key_exists($row[$i], $data)) {
                // Insert key
                $data[$row[$i]] = array();
            }
        }
        else {
            $level = $data[$row[$i-1]];

            if(array_key_exists($row[$i], $level)) {
                // Key exists
            }
            else {
                // Insert key

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "looking for help" .. Please show us what you tried already and where it failed you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We aren't here to write code for you, we are here to help you fix errors in what you've tried. In this case, to get any help you'll need to at least tell us how those arrays are linked together - a bunch of numeric keys means nothing.

Comment: Sorry about that!  Like I said, I'm querying my database which stores product information in a table.  The id is the product id in the database.  Post edited above.

Comment: Your hierarchy does not consider 5th element at all.

Comment: The sample rows I posted are just a small part of a huge table.  Sometimes they will have values, otherwise they will be blank and not considered.  Different products sometimes have different categories.

Comment: One thing that would make it all 1000% easier is to get associative arrays as data rather than the mysterious numeric indexes. Using `mysql_*`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has a good intention: using `$level` to hold the current depth. But at the moment this won't work, because you are copying via `$level = $data[$row[$i-1]];` - instead you need to [refer to it](http://www.php.net/manual/language.references.whatdo.php), e.g. with `$level =& $data[$row[$i-1]];`.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) [
    $id = array_shift($row);

    if (!isset($maxIterator))
        $maxIterator = count($row)-1;

    $current =& $result;
    for ($i=0; $i<$maxIterator; $i++) {
        if (empty($row[$i]))
            break;
        if (!array_key_exists($row[$i], $current))
            $current[ $row[$i] ] = array();
        $current =& $current[ $row[$i] ];
    }
    //for properly ended and wasn't broken out of sooner
    if ($i == $maxIterator) {
        if (!array_key_exists($row[$i], $current))
            $current[ $row[$i] ] = 1;
        else
            $current[ $row[$i] ]++;
    }
}
```

[`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/array_shift) basically does, what you needed two lines for: get the first element of an array and then remove it. Then I save the result of the count in a variable, so it doesn't need to be recalculated in every iteration of the `for` AND `while`.

Also I would suggest setting `$maxIterator` manually. With the shown result a good default would be `5`. This way all values before the 5th. will be used for nesting and the 5th itself will be used to count (in your example this is storage size).

As the `for` will execute `$i++` after the last iteration (and then it fails the condition and hence the loop breaks), it can be used for the counting.

---

Personally I would overthink what exactly you are doing and maybe use a specifc structure for that. However, this code should give you a good impression how it can be solved using references.

Comment: Thanks!  However, I think the break statement ends the loop too soon and doesn't get to the other values such as capacity.  It cuts out right after screensize.  Is there a way to have it ignore blank values and skip to the next loop?

Comment: Thank you kind sir!  Had no idea that was an option.